# Passing variable in PHP link

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php - insert a variable in an echo string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054989/php-insert-a-variable-in-an-echo-string)

I have a link that when it is clicked calls the next page and should pass two varibles to the page, the first is Manu and the second is fuel_type.

The problem is I can not seem to get the code to identify the variables and instead it passes the dollar sign and the variable name and not the value.

The code is below, i have tried writing this several different ways, but I am just running out of ideas.

```
 .'<a href=\act/manufacturer.php?manufacturer=$manu&fuel_type=$fuel_type>'.$manu.'</a>'.
```

Comment: You forgot to read the PHP documentation. The PHP manual quite clearly explains how variables are interpolated inside strings. In this case the difference between `'` and `"` is key. Please go read the manual...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to insert the var outside the '

like this:

```
.'<a href=\act/manufacturer.php?manufacturer='.$manu.'&fuel_type='.$fuel_type.'>'.$manu.'</a>'.
```

Answer (score 4):

First, be sure that the variables contain what you want (from the superglobal GET variable):

```
$manu = $_GET['manu'];
$fuel_type = $_GET['fuel_type'];
```

Then, you have two options:

1. Use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes, variables inside of quotes will be expanded

   ```
   "My dog is named $dog_name, and is $dog_age years old";
   ```
2. Concatenate the strings inside single quotes with variables:

   ```
   'My dog is named ' . $dog_name . ', and is ' . $dog_age . ' years old.';
   ```

Be absolutely certain, however that you sanitize the variables before using or displaying them to the browser. At a minimum, you want any HTML/JS code removed, then some checking to make sure the result is of the type and length that you expect. There are quite a few questions on SO discussing ways to do this, a quick search for *[php] sanitize GET variables* will turn them up.

Answer (score 2):

[Single quotes do not parse variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), while double quotes do.  Change your quotes around, and your link should work correctly.

Example:

```
."<a href=\act/manufacturer.php?manufacturer=$manu&fuel_type=$fuel_type>".$manu.'</a>'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes dont allow parsing of variables, double-quotes do. So you'd be better off doing something like:

```
"<a href=\act/manufacturer.php?manufacturer=$manu&fuel_type=$fuel_type>$manu</a>";
```

-- or in your case --

```
'<a href=\act/manufacturer.php?manufacturer='.$manu.'&fuel_type='.$fuel_type.'>'.$manu.'</a>'
```

Comment: this is the sum of mine and Daedalus's

Comment: @gabrielem Yeah. Great minds...

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your variables around curly braces to escape variable expressions:

```
'<a href=\act/manufacturer.php?manufacturer={$manu}&fuel_type={$fuel_type}>'.$manu.'</a>'.
```

Comment: This however _will not_ work.