# How can I put a PHP Variable in file_get_contents URL String?

Tags: php, json, variables, file-get-contents

I would like change the 1 in the URL below and pass PHP variable pulled from the website URL. I have everything else working except I'm having trouble getting a variable working in the middle of the URL file_get_contents below.

```
$listingstring = file_get_contents('http://example.com/1/lsitngs/');

$listingstring = file_get_contents('http://example.com/?variable/lsitngs/');
```

Comment: Are you asking how to perform string concatenation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - insert a variable in an echo string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054989/php-insert-a-variable-in-an-echo-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use double quotes for your string so you can place a variable inside of it and have it interpolated:

```
$listingstring = file_get_contents("http://example.com/$variable/lsitngs/");
```

You can also use concatenation:

```
$listingstring = file_get_contents('http://example.com/'.$variable.'/lsitngs/');
```

Comment: 2 for 1 special, bonus ;-)

Comment: ...and what a bargain they get!

Comment: What a great deal! Awesome thanks. I picked the second option.