# how can i get mysql record like a data?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi to all my question is some weird but i'll explane in here.

i want to record cv examples and user informations.
i have two table like that;

```
cv
*id *format
users
*id *name *age
```

in format cell include some html tags and $name , $age tags like that;

```
<p>
My name is <b>$name</b> and im <b>$age</b> years old.
<p>
```

my codes are like that;

```
$sqlcv = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from cv where id='2'"));
$text = $sqlcv['format'];

$sqluser = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from users where id='3'"));
$name = $sqluser['name'];
$age = $sqluser['age'];

echo $text;
```

result;
My name is **$name** and im **$age** years old.
so html tags works but name and age not shown :(
hope i can explane this one

Comment: That works exactly as is. Are you sure you're not using single quotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - insert a variable in an echo string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054989/php-insert-a-variable-in-an-echo-string)

Comment: This has nothing to do with mysql btw.

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, don't forget to mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
echo sprintf("Hi im %s and im %d years old.", "Darius", $age);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$age = 23;
$text = "Hi im Darius and im ".$age." years old";
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write $text like this:

```
$text = "Hi im Darius and im " . $age . " years old";
```

Else it will think $age is in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>My name is <b>$name</b> and I'm <b>$age</b> years old.<p>
```

I can't tell from your question, but you might have forgotten to wrap it in php. If that's the case, try using

```
<?php echo "<p>My name is <b>$name</b> and I'm <b>$age</b> years old.<p>"; ?>
```

or

```
<p>My name is <b><?=$name?></b> and I'm <b><?=$age?></b> years old.<p>
```

OR if you actually have the string "<p>My name is <b>$name</b> and I'm <b>$age</b> years old.<p>" in the database cell (I hope you don't) and want to replace the variables with custom values, I suggest using

```
$output = str_replace('$age', $yourAgeVariable, $theCellValue)
```

and similarly with $name. I think that wouldn't make sense to put that into a database column though, so I'm posting this other part just in case you actually did that.