# Not Pressing the URL

Tags: php

*Here is Code I used to Redirect*

```
<?php
// 301 Moved Permanently

$id1 = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$id2 = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
header("Location: https://example1.com/away.php?to=https://example2.com/sample-page/?$id1", true, 301);

exit();
?>
```

**When I Pressing The URL**

https://example2.com/sample-page/?id1=4567&id2=name

**Get The Result**

https://example2.com/sample-page/?id1=4567

Not Pressing the URL With Id2=name

**Can any one help me to fix this Problem**

**Want a Result this**

https://example2.com/sample-page/?id1=4567&id2=name

Comment: You want to ignore `id2` ? You can unset it at the beginning of your code. `unset($_GET['id2']);`

Comment: I want id2 could be executed after Pressing the url.. Only id1 is Executed after Pressing the url not id2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php - insert a variable in an echo string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054989/php-insert-a-variable-in-an-echo-string)

Answer (score 0):

It simple you didn't use both id to your URL just edit it like this:

```
header("Location: https://example1.com/away.php?to=https://example2.com/sample-page/?id1={$id1}&id2={$id2}", true, 301);
```

Comment: https://example2.com/sample-page/?id1=m333&id2=576576  got this result https://example2.com/sample-page/?id=id=m333